# make the `yes` command exit with non-zero return code?

Tags: linux, shell

A friend bet that a program as simple as `yes` may never go wrong.

https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/yes.c

I think it's possible to create extreme scenarios when yes could not complete successfully, however my C and shell skills are limited.

Are there any ways to make `yes` command return with non-zero code? ulimit the memory? Make stdout a broken fd?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow's scope is limited to _practical_ questions "about a problem you actually face". This is pure academic curiosity; there is no technical question whose answer changes how anyone goes about the practice of software development here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  while (full_write (STDOUT_FILENO, buf, bufused) == bufused)
    continue;
  error (0, errno, _("standard output"));
  main_exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

> Are there any ways to make yes command return with non-zero code?

The program you posted *always completes* unsuccessfully. `EXIT_FAILURE` typically is `1`.

You can close the file descriptor `yes` writes to, for example `yes >&-`.

You can exit also `yes` with a signal, in which case it will also exit with because of the signal, typically reported by utilities as an exit status equal to 128 + signal number.

You can pass an invalid command line argument, like `yes --invalid`, in which case it will also exit with `1`.

Finally, `yes --help` is the only case where `yes` program exits with success.

Comment: That's the signal case.